# How to output frame rate, bitrate etc. to console in GStreamer for RTSP source?

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm using the following command to capture from RTSP source:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e rtspsrc location=${RTSP_SOURCE} ! queue ! rtph264depay \
     ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=capture.mkv
```

Console output is not too informative: it doesn't show neither bitrate nor framerate. If I just set GST_DEBUG="4" then output is way too verbose.

How to dump to console capture info periodically such as FPS (most important for me), bitrate (less important), captured file size (lesser important)?

Comment: Maybe off-topic, but why not use ffmpeg?

Comment: using `gst-launch-1.0`, this is not possible. Write a python script or any other programming language and try to read the property using `get_property("fps/bitrate")`.